# How the single sign out to make work in Salesforce as IDP using SAML

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am using Salesforce as an Idp and my portal as SP.
I can login and can redirected to my page.
My Qn is how can I check if I have the login session active when I browse from page to page of my portal ?
If from another connected app or from IDP session is expired and/ signed out - how will my portal will get that status ?
Can anybody please refer me any document/code on sales force regarding this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your portal does not need to know the state of the session at the identity provider. The session in SP (your portal) has nothing to do with the session in IdP (Salesforce). If the IdP session times out, the SP session can still be active. This is a valid scenario.